# VBA to COM Exposed .NET assembly - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vb.net, vba, com

Are shared properties accessible from a COM exposed .NET assembly?

**VBA**

```
Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim objAppSingleton As Object
    Set objAppSingleton = CreateObject("Pitchbook.CommonUtils.Application.PitchbookAppSingleton")
    appExcel = objAppSingleton.CurrentPitchbookExcelApp
```

**VB.NET**

```
<ProgId("Pitchbook.CommonUtils.Application.PitchbookAppSingleton")> _
Public Class PitchbookAppSingleton

    Private Shared _currentPitchbookExcelApplication As PitchbookAppExcel
    Private Shared _syncLockExcel As Object = New Object()

   Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentPitchbookExcelApp As PitchbookAppExcel
        Get
            If _currentPitchbookExcelApplication Is Nothing Then
                                    SyncLock [_syncLockExcel]
                    If _currentPitchbookExcelApplication Is Nothing Then
                        Dim currPitchbookExcelApplication As New PitchbookAppExcel()
                        _currentPitchbookExcelApplication = currPitchbookExcelApplication
                    End If
                End SyncLock
            End If
            Return _currentPitchbookExcelApplication
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Public Class PitchbookAppExcel
    Inherits PitchbookApp

    Protected Friend Sub New()
        MyBase.New()                        
    End Sub

End Class
```

The line appExcel = objAppSingleton.CurrentPitchbookExcelApp gives the error:
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Can't you just access the shared private object from a non shared property declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple problem but if anyone doesn't know the answer already it's **no you cannot access shared properties from a COM exposed .NET assembly**. At least not directly... you can however access shared properties if you create an instance wrapper.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?p=1326018 
http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=817248

In my case I used the Facade pattern to create an object specifically for use by VBA that exposed the relevant shared utility functions via instances. Thanks to everyone for their comments.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You need to say **`Set`** in VB to set an object variable.

```
Set appExcel = objAppSingleton.CurrentPitchbookExcelApp
```

If you don't say "Set" then VBA will look for the default method, and call that, to obtain a non-object type. If there is no default method defined (dispid=0) then it will fail with the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still get the same error even with Set appExcel = objAppSingleton.CurrentPitchbookExcelApp

Comment: @ernie99, Then I don't know. Have you tried running the VB host in the Visual Studio debugger and sticking a breakpoint in?

Comment: I'm using the builtin Visual Basic IDE in Excel. I have set a break point and stepped through the code. Looking in the locals window the objAppSingleton instantiates correctly i.e. it's value is not nothing. When you expand the object there are no members listed. I would expect to see the members of that object listed but I think that's just a limitation of the IDE (it only shows variables not properties) rather than a problem. I obviously don't know much about VBA. Everything seems to be setup correctly. I think it's because it's a shared property. I'll keep digging, thanks anyway.

Comment: @ernie99, Doh! I didn't notice it was a shared property. You are correct, the property shouldn't be shared, only the private variable it uses underneath.

Comment: So shared properties are not supported by VBA? Should I be using modules rather than shared classes? All of my utility classes don't require instantiation and are shared (as opposed to modules) as shared seemed to allow better encapsulation. Changing to modules is going to be painful but I will do it if I have to.

Comment: @ernie99, not modules, no. Use a non-singleton class which exposes methods to retrieve singletons is a perfectly reasonable way to solve this problem. In other words: The methods have to be instance (non-shared) methods to be visible on the object from VBA or script, but they can still just return a Shared variable to implement a singleton. Basically if you drop the word "Shared" from the method it should work as far as I can see.

Comment: I had hoped that the utility classes could be used by both .NET and VBA. Dropping the shared creates a huge mess as you then have to instantiate an object everytime you want to use a shared utility function in .NET. I guess I could create another set of classes specifically for exposing shared members using an instance but that would be a massive duplication of code. Doesn't sound like I have a choice though. Thank you for all your input. I will go and cry into my beer now :)

Comment: @ernie99 just create a single helper object for use from VBA, which wraps only the utility functions that VBA needs.